# Text wrap with chevron on right in React Native ListView item renderer

Tags: react-native

I am trying to have a list view show up that looks similar to this. The problem I am trying to solve is regarding word wrapping of the label.  I do have it working with the code below, but it feels like a hack and doesn't work with device rotation. There has to be a way to do it without using Dimensions and styling.

[image]

Here is what I have.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  StyleSheet,
  Dimensions,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

import Moment from 'moment'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

class ProjectListItemRenderer extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    //alert(Dimensions.get('window').height)

  }

  render() {

    return (
      <View style={styles.projectRow}>
        <View style={{width: Dimensions.get('window').width - 50}}>
          <Text style={styles.itemName}>{this.props.name}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.itemDetails}>{`${Moment(this.props.lastUpdated).fromNow()}`}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.moreContainer}>
          <Icon name="chevron-right" size={15} style={styles.moreIcon} />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  projectRow: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    padding: 15,
   },

   itemName: {
     fontSize: 18,
     color: '#4A90E2',
   },

   itemDetails: {
     fontSize: 12,
     color: '#BBBBBB',
   },

   moreContainer: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },

   moreIcon: {
     color: "#d6d7da"
   }

});

module.exports = ProjectListItemRenderer;
```

The other option I tried was absolute positioning, with the label being 20px from the right, and then absolute positioning the chevron on the right. The problem I ran into there was trying to figure out the height of the individual listItem renderer after it is rendered (and word wrapped).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem comes from having `flexDirection: 'row'` in the `View` containing your text. This makes the text overflow to the right instead of wrapping. If you want your text to wrap, the containing `View` must have `flexDirection: 'column'` in the style.

I've modified your code accordingly:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  StyleSheet,
  Dimensions,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

import Moment from 'moment'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

class ProjectListItemRenderer extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    //alert(Dimensions.get('window').height)
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <View style={styles.projectRow}>
        <View style={styles.projectText}>
          <Text style={styles.itemName}>{this.props.name}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.itemDetails>
            {`${Moment(this.props.lastUpdated).fromNow()}`}
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.moreContainer}>
          <Icon name="chevron-right" size={15} style={styles.moreIcon} />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  projectText: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column'
  },

  projectRow: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    padding: 15,
  },

   itemName: {
     fontSize: 18,
     color: '#4A90E2',
   },

   itemDetails: {
     fontSize: 12,
     color: '#BBBBBB',
   },

   moreContainer: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },

   moreIcon: {
     color: "#d6d7da"
   }

});

module.exports = ProjectListItemRenderer;
```

The only difference is I replaced `{width: Dimensions.get('window').width - 50}` with `{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column'}`.

Comment: Darn, I could have sworn I tried that! I must have had an issue with my code when I tested that.  This works fine. Thanks!